# Use of CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Tags: c#, decimal, cultureinfo

I'm working on a project that uses decimals in a textbox. I'm currently developing in a machine that has decimal separators set to "," instead of "." so I had to use this sentence when parsing text string into decimal:

```
decimal number = Decimal.Parse(number.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now... Is CultureInfo.InvariantCulture the right thing to do or should I use CurrentCulture instead?

Thank you,

Matias.

Comment: "right" and "wrong" are in the eye of the observer :)

Comment: Can you show an example value of `number.Text`?

Comment: Here's an example of number.text: 0.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For user input, you usually want `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. The fact that *you're* using a locale that's not natural to you is not the usual user case - if the user has `,` as the decimal point in their whole system, they're probably used to using that, instead of your preferred `.`. In other words, while you're testing on a system with locale like that, *learn to use `,` instead of `.`* - it's part of what makes locale testing useful :)

On the other hand, if you're e.g. storing the values in a configuration file or something like that, you really want to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

The thinking is rather simple - is it the user's data (=> `CurrentCulture`), or is it supposed to be global (=> `InvariantCulture`)?

Comment: Thanks Luaan, that makes lot of sense, I guess is not a programming thing but rather what I need from an user interface perspective as well as internal code handling

Answer (score 0):

If you do a correctly internationalized program...

A) If you are using Winforms or WPF or in general the user will "work" on the machine of the program, then input parsing should be done with the `CurrentCulture`

B) If you are web-programming, then the user should be able to select its culture, and `CurrentCulture` (the culture of the web-server) should be only used as a default

And then,

A) data you save "internally" (so to be written and then read by your program) should use `InvariantCulture`,

B) data you interchange with other apps would be better to be written with `InvariantCulture` (unless the other app is badly written and requires a specific format),

C) files you export to the user should follow the previous rules (the ones about user interface), unless you are using a "standard-defined format" like XML (then use Xml formatters)